# How to get 8 columns per row? [Javascript , Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom, bootstrap-4

So i am here wrote this simple function for searching movies and manipulating them in the dom.and the problem here is when a movie name is typed the api response back with at least 20/30 recommendations.And i want the fetched data to be distributed in 8 columns per row.So i wrote this function :

> Javascript part :

```
 db.multisearch()
  .then(data=>{
     var div=document.getElementById('call');
     var output='';
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     var poster=data[i].poster_path;
     var title=data[i].title;

for(let j=0;j<=8;j++){
  output +=`<div class="col-sm">
  <div class="card mb-3">
      <img class="card-img-top" src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342//${poster}' alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="text-block"><p>${title}</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
  }
 }
div.innerHTML=output;
});
```

> HTML part that im manipulating :

```
<section class="movie-page">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="call"></div>
</div>
```

But Instead of the desired outcome ,it just repeats one movie 8 times.

[image]

And I am trying to get the model to be somewhat like this each row without repeating any movie:

[image]

I am a newbie so i might have missed something. Please do help .

Comment: try do not use the second for

Comment: Have you considered [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), or [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead of Bootstrap?

Comment: If i don't specify the column number in 2nd loop, it stacks movies on each row as much as possible, like 13 movies per row. and it does not look good. looks kinda messy

Comment: @David Thomas Ah nope not yet.

Comment: Should you be interested: [simple grid demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fxmko48j/1/), [simple flexbox demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fxmko48j/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should be like the following; you need to close the current `row` after every 8th item and then open a new `row`.

```
    var output = '<div class="row">';

    for(let j=1; j<=data.lenght; j++){

        output +=`<div class="col-xs-1">
            content into column
        </div> \n`;

        if(j !== 0 && j%8 === 0) {
            output += '</div><div class="row">';
        }
    }

   output += '</div>';
```

See the working example below:

```js
var output = '<div class="row">';

for(let j = 1; j<= 50; j++){


  output +=`<div class="col-xs-1">
  ${j}
 </div> \n`;

  if(j !== 0 && j%8 === 0) {
    output += '</div><div class="row">';
  }
}

output += '</div>';

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.row .col-xs-1 {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 8.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```